# I want to use this script in Omega subteheme

Tags: javascript, theming

I want to use [this script](http://spoonfedproject.com/jquery/jquery-image-slide-on-hover-effect/) in my Omega sub-theme. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: themename.info or [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).

Long answer: If you always want it to load just use the info file and add a [js] entry. Google can help you there.

Depending on when you'd like that JS to load you might want to define it only when nodes of a certain type are displayed, etc. This changes where you put `drupal_add_js()` in your template.php.

If you want it only when you display nodes then stick it in `THEMENAME_preprocess_node()` and you can use the `$vars` in there to conditionally load it on a particular node type only, etc